# How to remove the article id from Joomla link

Tags: joomla

how can i remove the article id from the link?
http://new.autoankauf-start.de/259-autoankauf-kfz-ankauf-in-gummersbach.html

when i do this in the  Articles: Options Integrartion  it switches the link to :
http://new.autoankauf-start.de/?view=article&id=259:autoankauf-kfz-ankauf-in-gummersbach&catid=19

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange. After joining the dedicated community where all Joomla questions should be posted, I can assist you in migrating the page if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps for doing this.

1. Go to `content > articles`.
2. Click the `Options` button from the top-right corner. This will send you to the options page.
3. Go to the `Integration` tab.
4. From the **Routing** section select *URL Routing* as `Modern`.
5. Select *Remove Ids from URLs* as `Yes`.

That's all you need to do for removing the IDs from the URL.

[image]

Comment: when i do this in the Articles: Options Integrartion it switches the link to : http://new.autoankauf-start.de/?view=article&id=259:autoankauf-kfz-ankauf-in-gummersbach&catid=19

Comment: What is your Joomla version? And did you enable the `SEF` URL option?

Comment: latest joomla version and u mean with sef ( the search engnihsefrienldy  yes and url rewrtie too

Comment: If you are not using any external extension for managing URLs then there no reason for it. You can communicate with me at `sajeeb07ahamed@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your site/content is organized. Here are some tips that can help you:

1. Have a look at this article:
   https://www.joomshaper.com/blog/making-joomla-site-seo-friendly-by-removing-id-from-urls
2. You can also create a menu item which has associated your article (New Menu Item → Menu Item Type: Single Article). If you don't want your menu item to appear in the front-end you can make it hidden (Link type → Display in Menu: No)
3. You can use plugins like [sef404SEF](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sh404sef/).

Comment: when i do this in the Articles: Options Integrartion it switches the link to : http://new.autoankauf-start.de/?view=article&id=259:autoankauf-kfz-ankauf-in-gummersbach&catid=19